# loading a drawable resource into a texture and rendering it

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to understand OpenGL ES 2.0 in android. I got a code from a tutorial, but I do not understand how the texture works. I can't even understand where the rendering took place. Here is the code I got.

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(GL10 gl) {
    // set up the surface
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glHint(
        GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,
        GL10.GL_FASTEST);
    gl.glClearColor(0.4f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.5f);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // fetch the checker-board
    initImage(gl);
}
@Override
public void drawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    // apply the checker-board to the shape
    gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
    gl.glTexEnvx(
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,
        GL10.GL_MODULATE);
    gl.glTexParameterx(
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
        GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterx(
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
        GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    // animation
    int t = (int) (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % (10 * 1000L));
    gl.glTranslatef(6.0f - (0.0013f * t), 0, 0);
    // draw
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuf);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuf);
    gl.glDrawElements(
        GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,
        5,
        GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuf);
}

private void initImage(GL10 gl) {
    int[] textures = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
        GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
        GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
        GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
        GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexEnvf(
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,
        GL10.GL_REPLACE);
    InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.cb);
    Bitmap image;
    try { image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in); }
    finally {
        try { in.close(); } catch(IOException e) { }
    }
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, image, 0);
    image.recycle();
}
```

Can anyone explain to me where the image is loaded from a drawable file, where the conversion to texture, and where the rendering took place? I just can't seem to understand this. I'm familiar with how to do it in OpenGL but it seems OpenGL ES 2.0 uses a different technique?

Comment: Note that you're not doing any OpenGL ES **2** here, your code is OpenGL ES **1** as you're not using any shader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, image, 0);` is a utility function which converts an android Bitmap into an OpenGL texture.

When this is called, it stores the bitmap in `image` into the currently bound texture, which in your case is `textures[0]`.

`glDrawElements` is the command that actually fires off the rendering call. If you want to know what any of the other functions do, I suggest taking a look at their online help pages.